Fujitsu Siemens P756 PC does not boot and does not enter BIOS menu after update to 22.04.01 LTS
After accepting the offer to update from 22.04 LTS to 24.04.01 LTS the system stands still during the boot process showing only the "FUJITSU" splash screen. (To be precise: The "FUJITSU" shows up, then the screen gets black for ~1sec, then it re-appears. The "black-screen" time is normally where one can press F2 and F12 to enter the BIOS)

Entering the BIOS does not work any longer.
The system does not start.
BIOS recovery cannot be entered (also not by changing the jumpers on the main board). The USB stick is not detected and not booted.

After mounting the same M2 memory in a second PC with the system boots up and enters the new Ubuntu Linux. After the next reboot the same happens also to this second PC. It stands still in the same position, not being able to enter BIOS or the OS.

Mounting back the earlier working M2 memory into the PC does not recover the system.
removing the backup battery does not help
The keyboard is USB, same slot that worked to enter the BIOS before. PS/2 is not available to me.

Any idea on what happens to the system that is permanent?
Any idea what else can help to recover two earlier well working PCs (Fujitsu Siemens P756/E94+)?

I have exactly the same problem on the same hardware (Fujitsu Siemens P756/E85+). I installed Ubuntu 22.04 and everything worked fine. I then upgraded to 24.04 and rebooted. Since then, the PC is basically bricked. It just shows the FUJITSU splash screen and doesn't respond to the keyboard. Also, booting from a rescue DVD or USB does not work.

grubmen availabel? Is the last jammy kernel on system? Is your bios/uefi  available after you remove the M2 memory?

The bios/uefi is not longer configurable - the menus cannot be reached. Since my boot device was the m.2, only, and booting from that does not work, I did not find a solution. Still two PCs are bricked.

Wait tomorrow i have Something in mind. In a German Forum we could solve IT after the brick Desaster from Release 17.04.

so no grubmenu; am I correct? Thats bad I thought we could do something over grubshell.

I think you have to run the BIOS software here from a CD drive? - https://support.ts.fujitsu.com/indexdownload.asp?Softwareguid=28e7bb86-83cc-45bf-ab24-e41e024537d7 It sounds like some of these Fujitsu computers don't have recover partitions (this is for a laptop but maybe similar): https://www.reddit.com/r/retrocomputing/comments/1dhhq1p/how_do_i_boot_and_fresh_install_an_os_on_this/

No, grubmenu is not reachable. It seems, that the bios gets destroyed - or at least the entry into it. Even bios entry with jumper on the board does not work.

Another try remove bios battery und power cable and the nvme.  Push at least 1 min or so the powerbutton.  Put only power cable on and try to start.

As stated above: removing the backup battery was tried before the first question was raised.

@user68186 It is certainly a close one but the question does deal with an issue relating to the upgrade of an Ubuntu system. Certainly it could be argued that the problem is actually distro agnostic and perhaps hardware / specific system specific, but I have erred on the generous side with this one...

Finally I was able to recover one PC using the following information:
From the Fujitsu pages download the following files:

FTS_BootStick_100_1088425.EXE
FTS_D3401A1xAdminpackageCompressedFlashFiles_V50011R1330_1259651.ZIP
FTS_BIOSHandbuchfürSystemboardsmitIntel[R]100Seri_042016_1211724.PDF
FTS_MainboardD3401D3402D3417Shortdescription_112015_1147495.PDF

Using the information in document 3, chapter "Flash BIOS update with a USB stick" one gets to know, how to create a bootable USB Stick.
For this one uses the executable from document 1 to create an empty bootable stick. Then one copies all files included in the zip file 2 to the stick.
From the chapter "BIOS Recovery Update" in document 3 one gets to know, that there is a recovery jumper on the board. The location is described in document 4. Please note, that the recovery gets activated when the bridge is connected to the leftmost pins: These are the once with the lines pointing downwards from the pins, not the pair that is marked with darker background.
Now perform the following steps:

Unplug the power supply.
Set the recovery bridge as described above
Remove the M.2 device, unplug the CD-ROM. Ensure there is no other device in the system at all.
Plugin the USB stick into the back panel USB plugs.
Connect the power supply
Start the PC.
Wait, even though the monitor does not show anything. The PC will also re-boot. Simply wait for ~5 minutes.

For me nothing happend at first. There was no action to be performed - not like the instructions told. But still after some time the system showed, that the BIOS was recovered/updated. From then on, one can enter the BIOS and start with a new configuration.
Before the shut-down insert a gparted CD into the CD drive and reboot. Ensure booting from the CD works. Then shutdown from gparted again, but ensure to put in the CD again, before equipping the system with the M.2 device and booting up. By this it should be possible to format the M.2 to a new operating system different to ubuntu 24.04.01.
